# Creating a list from other lists and varying the number of elements that get added

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-construction

Suppose I have

```
 listA = {M, F}
```

and

```
ListB = {a,b,c}
```

I want to make a new

```
listC = {{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}
```

Where I tell Mathematica how many copies of a particular element to make in listC.

`Outer[]` seems like a good start but it returns the combined elements as a two item list. For example I get `{M, a}` instead of `M a`.

Comment: Do you mean `M * a` or a new symbol called `Ma` ?

Comment: "Where I tell Mathematica how many copies of a particular element to make in listC" in what format do you want to supply this information?

Comment: `Outer` seems like the answer, it combines, and wraps a combination of elements with a specified function, if the function is `Times`, you can get get a M, if it's `List`, you get {M, a} instead.

Comment: I edited your question trying to make it easier to read. Next time please try to do it yourself.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for the editing. I am new to the site so I am still trying sort out how things work. I will do that next time.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I am looking for a new symbol Ma. Since I am starting to learn how Mathematica works, I am also interested in understanding both cases.

Comment: @BoLe Since the list would be in an order I define. I was thinking of supplying the information using a Range[] function. For example from range 0-5 make n copies, from range 6-10 make k copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed your comment under the question that you actually do want new symbols.  I shall give an example of that and also multiplication.

It is more efficient to perform the operation (multiplication, etc.) and then make the copies, rather than making copies and performing the operation anew on each.

```
f[A_, B_, R_, f_: Times] := Inner[ConstantArray, Outer[f, A, B], R, Join]

f[{M, F}, {a, b, c}, {1, 3, 2}
```

> ```
> {{a M, b M, b M, b M, c M, c M}, {a F, b F, b F, b F, c F, c F}}
> ```

Symbols:

```
makeSym = Symbol @ ToString @ Row @ {##} &;

f[{M, F}, {a, b, c}, {1, 3, 2}, makeSym]
```

> ```
> {{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}
> ```

With argument checking for practical use:

```
f[A_List, B_List, R : {__Integer}, f_: Times] /;
 Min[R] >= 0 && Length@B == Length@R :=
  Inner[ConstantArray, Outer[f, A, B], R, Join]
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple to follow the code. However I am not sure I get how `makeSym` fits in the picture. Is it replacing `f_:Times` which is the 4th argument when `f[A_, B_, R_, f_: Times]` gets defined. If that is true, then makeSym is being passed into `Outer` as the first argument which makes the return value a string?

Comment: @spaceKnot You're welcome.  I see that there is an error in my code which I will now correct.  (I forgot to update the right-hand-side when I updated the left.)  The `Pattern`: `f_: Times` defines an `Optional` parameter with a default values of `Times`.  If no fourth argument is given `Times` is used where `f` appears; if an argument is given it instead is used.  Sorry for the mistake, and if anything isn't clear please ask again.

Comment: Thank you again! That clarified my question :)

Comment: @spaceKnot Are you aware that you can [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) one answer that you find fully satisfactory (and you can change the Accept at a later time)?  You are not required to do so but it is appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Wiazrd Sorry, still learning the rules.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Ma is the product M * a, you could state the number of copies:

```
copies = {1, 3, 2};
```

Then make these copies:

```
listD = Flatten[Inner[Table[#1, {#2}] &, listB, copies, List]]
```

> {a, b, b, b, c, c}

And finally combine them with the first list:

```
Outer[Times, listA, listD]
```

> {{a M, b M, b M, b M, c M, c M}, {a F, b F, b F, b F, c F, c F}}

**Update**

If you really want a new symbol Ma, you could perhaps do this with strings.

```
listA = {"M", "F"};
listB = {"a", "b", "c"};
copies = {1, 3, 2};
listD = Flatten[Inner[Table[#1, {#2}] &, listB, copies, List]];
Outer[ToExpression[#1 <> #2] &, listA, listD]
```

> {{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}

Comment: @spaceKnot Very flexible, this `Outer`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of BoLe's answer using `Outer`:

```
lA = {"M", "F"};
lB = {"a", "b", "c"};
lC = {1, 3, 2};

Outer[ToExpression[#1 <> #2] &, lA, Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ Transpose@{lB, lC}]] 
(*using AbsoluteTiming*)

{0.0001178, {{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}}

Outer[ToExpression[#1 <> #2] &, lA, Flatten[Inner[Table[#1, {#2}] &, lB, lC, List]]]
(*using AbsoluteTiming*)

{0.0002433, {{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mf = {M, F};
abc = {a, b, c};

Map[
  Symbol @* StringJoin,
  Map[
   ToString,
   Thread[{#, abc}] & /@ mf,
   {3}],
  {2}][[All, {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}]]
```

{{Ma, Mb, Mb, Mb, Mc, Mc}, {Fa, Fb, Fb, Fb, Fc, Fc}}